# Is E(Y|X) a function of Y?

Tags: econometrics, conditional-expectation, distributions

I'm slightly confused by a question I have encountered, it's a true or false question stating:

'The expression $E_{(Y|X)} (Y|X)$ is a function of $Y$.'

My automatic instinct was, well yes of course it is.

Assuming that the variables are continuous, I think formally (please correct me if I'm wrong as I'm still getting used to the notation):

$$E_{(Y|X)} (Y|X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y \ g(y|x) \ dy$$

where

$$g(y|x) =\frac {f_{x,y}(x,y)}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{x,y}(x,y)dy}$$

Which I think demonstrates it is a function of $Y$, however the answer was 'false'. Have I made a mistake interpreting the notation? Or is it because the expression is a function of both $Y$ and $X$, something which I was aware of however misinterpreted the question.

**On second thought I just realised I'm doing prep work for econometrics, is it because $Y$ is the dependent variable, $X$ the explanatory and therefore $ Y=\mu(X)$ for some function $\mu$.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $E_{Y|X}(Y|X)$ is a function of $X$. The conditional density function $g(y|x)$ depends on both $y$ and $x$ but then you integrate $yg(y|x)$ over $y$ when taking the expectation.

Comment: @Neznajka, to make you comment useful you should provide some explanation, not just a plain, undefended statement.

Comment: @Richard Hardy . I agree. I expanded my comment.

Comment: Hint: Is $1/2 = \int_0^1 x dx$ a function of x?

Comment: @Student001 - No it's a constant, 1/2? Okay I think I understand, as you've inegrated over y, we're left with just a function of x, as the ys effectively disappear out of the expression?

Comment: @Neznajka Thanks for the input greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Nik-D: yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: The $Y$ (and all notion of $y$) will vanish when the integral is evaluated - however this is a technicality. If you consider expectation as a function (which I try to) it depends on both $X$ and $Y$ - if you're doing it numerically also depends on both. Please don't remember this as some sort of "fact"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$g_{Y\mid X = x}(y\mid x) =\frac {f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy} = \frac {f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{X}(x)}$$ and so
$$E[Y\mid X = x] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y g_{Y\mid X = x}(y\mid x) \ dy
= \frac{1}{f_{X}(x)} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y f_{X,Y}(x,y) \ dy = h(x)\tag{1}$$
Thus, the *number* $E[Y\mid X = x]$ depends on your choice of $x$.
It does not depend on $y$ at all; $y$ is just a variable of
integration and disappears when we plug in the limits on that
integral in $(1)$.
We can think of this number as the *realization* or *sample* of
a random variable $Z$ where $Z$ has value $E[Y\mid X = x]$ whenever
it so happens that $X$ has value $x$. So, we can think of the *random
variable* $Z = E[Y \mid X]$ as a *function* $h(X)$ of $X$ 
since if we sample
$X$ we can figure out what the sample of $Z$ must be.  $Z$ is not
a function of $Y$ at all!

The *law of iterated expectation* says that the *expected value*
of $Z = h(X)$, which is a function of $X$ and not at all of $Y$, quite
by magic, happens to equal $E[Y]$, the expected value of $Y$,
that is, 
$$E[Z] = E[h(X)] = E\left[\, E[Y\mid X]\,\right] = E[Y].$$

Comment: Thanks very much!
Quick question, is there a mistype in your answer, on the second line in the third expression,  once factored out $\frac {1}{f_x(x)}$ is there still meant to be the conditional probability $g_{y|x}$ or is it meant to be just the joint distribution $f_{x,y}(x,y)$

Comment: @ Nik-D You are correct: it should be $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and not $g$ at all.  I have fixed the error.

Answer (score 2):

@Neznajka pointed out the formal basis for why $E[Y|X]$ is a function of $X$, not $Y$. At a more abstract level, you can also see this by considering that $E[Y|X]$ takes as input a value of $X$ and maps it to a conditional expected value of $Y$. Therefore, you can write $E[Y|X]$ as a plain old univariate function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto E[Y|X=x]$.

So, since the distribution of $Y$ remains fixed, then it has to be a function of $X$.